# Making functions increasingly generic

Tags: c++, xml, function, generics

I am currently working on a generic C++ function for reading in data from a database, and then printing it to a file in XML format. Each database file gets a structure with basic information in it about the database file (it's a proprietary database).

The trouble is, while it's perfectly generic for most things, there is a single database file that uses a sort of union, where a column determines the contents of the remaining columns. These are to get their own indentation level, like a child in the main record. The secondary problem is that there might end up being a file with an unknown number of child indentations.

What would I need to do to make this function as generic as possible to avoid having to put in an if statement for that specific file? I have a means (potentially) to make it work with one child, but when it gets to multiple child indentations things get a little crazy and hazy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing a `structure with basic information`, pass one or more function pointers (i.e. "callbacks") which take care of parsing individual parts. That way, your generic function implements the toplevel algorithm but the lower level details are handled by functions provided by the caller.